# Angular Flex: 3 divs: middle one should shrink depending on the context of upper and lower div's

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am a kind of new with Angular Flex. I have 3 `divs` and I want there to be a `div` dynamic space between the upper and lower one so that the lower `div` is located on the bottom depending on the bottom and top `div's` taken space.

Is this possible to achieve with Angular Flex?

Here are 3 div's

```
<div class="row" fxFlex="basis">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 p-small-text">
    {{app._description}}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black;" fxFlex="grow">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">no content</div>
</div>

<div class="row p-row-top-padding" fxFlex="basis">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">dynamic content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you just want a column with a div on top, followed by a space, then another div below? But the space in between the top and bottom div changes dynamically based on what?

Comment: @Narm based on top div.

Comment: Could you please further explain what you are trying to archive? Some examples would be helpful.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I have 3 divs. They are all in one parent div which is fixed size. I want the middle div of the three to have dynamic height depending upon the top div of the three.